# CSS styling on TeX.sx seems to be gone

Tags: support

I'm looking at the TeX.sx site, and it looks like it's not being styled. Any ideas what's going on? I'm not seeing this on other SEs.

Comment: Never mind, seems to be resolved. Did anyone else see this though?

Comment: (I voted to close, as I think this may have just been a local screwup.)

Comment: Ok, closed for now. Feel free to edit when you got new information, we could reopen it.

Comment: Thanks. If I see it again I'll put something here.

Comment: CSS is stored in a separate file. When a browser fails to retrieve it but succeeds in downloading the web page proper, you get a page with no styles applied.

Comment: I'm aware of that. This observation was on multiple browsers with several refreshes on each. I did not look at the CSS that had been downloaded though. Probably should have.

Answer (score 3):

I noticed missing styling several times, but only when I used a bad connection, usually over 3G / UMTS, even though the page texts could be loaded. A page refresh, after the connection got better, helped in those cases.

As you mentioned other SE sites, it's a good idea to test another site right at the same time when the TeX site style looks bad. I'll check this as well when it would happen again.

Comment: I checked them at the same time. All the time I was having issues with TeX.sx there were none with meta, Mathematics, Theoretical Physics or Area 51.

Comment: Does TeX.sx have any bandwidth hungry elements that the others don't?